# App crashes in Release but not in debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

My iOS app get data from webservice xml and parse in my project. When debugging with iPad (Real Device) all are ok but when release as ad hoc app crashed. I got the following crash report.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x22d28676 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x348d6e12 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x22d2de90 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
3   CoreFoundation                  0x22d2bac4 ___forwarding___ + 696
4   CoreFoundation                  0x22c5c124 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   AGD                             0x0010de0c -[QRConfirmViewController CuttingDynamicKeyNode:] (QRConfirmViewController.m:583)
6   Foundation                      0x23b06bb8 _endElementNs + 592
7   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x34eae2b2 xmlParseEndTag2 + 686
8   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x34eab58a xmlParseTryOrFinish + 2014
9   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x34eaa764 xmlParseChunk + 576
10  Foundation                      0x23b042bc -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 292
11  Foundation                      0x23b04504 -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 876
12  Foundation                      0x23b0468a -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] + 282
13  AGD                             0x0010db22 -[QRConfirmViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] (QRConfirmViewController.m:516)
14  CFNetwork                       0x22687d58 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 52
15  CFNetwork                       0x22687d10 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 180
16  CFNetwork                       0x22687e04 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 32
17  CFNetwork                       0x22547c1a ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 74
18  CFNetwork                       0x226018ba ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 66
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x34ffbbd2 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x35005182 _dispatch_block_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 442
21  CFNetwork                       0x22538caa RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 14
22  CoreFoundation                  0x22c3cb4c CFArrayApplyFunction + 32
23  CFNetwork                       0x22538b92 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 178
24  CFNetwork                       0x22538a5c MultiplexerSource::perform() + 212
25  CFNetwork                       0x225388f4 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 44
26  CoreFoundation                  0x22cebbfa __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
27  CoreFoundation                  0x22ceb7e8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 448
28  CoreFoundation                  0x22ce9b56 __CFRunLoopRun + 790
29  CoreFoundation                  0x22c3d114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
30  CoreFoundation                  0x22c3cf00 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
31  GraphicsServices                0x2bddaac4 GSEventRunModal + 156
32  UIKit                           0x26e7ff10 UIApplicationMain + 140
33  AGD                             0x0006d57a main (main.m:16)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x3504586e tlv_get_addr + 42
```

But I can't find any error in my method. My method is as follow:

```
-CuttingDynamicKeyNode:(NSString *)nodes{
    NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nodes];

    NSString * _key = AES_KEYS;
    StringEncryption *crypto = [[[StringEncryption alloc] init] autorelease];
    CCOptions padding = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;

    //Decrypt method
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:result];
    NSData * decrypteStringData = [crypto decrypt:data key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

    NSString * stringNodesResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decrypteStringData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    /// Get Nodes Elements........

    AppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    //ObjectSVNotification * objNoti = [[ObjectSVNotification alloc]init];

    GDataXMLDocument * doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]init];

    [doc initWithXMLString:stringNodesResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (doc == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Doc is NuLL :::: ");
    }
    if (doc) {
        // For Store in Notification Table ......
        NSArray *arrayField43 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field43" error:NULL];
        NSArray *arrayField44= [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field44" error:NULL];

        NSArray * arrayField118 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field118" error:NULL];
        NSArray * arrayField117 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field117" error:NULL];
        NSArray * arrayField119 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field119" error:NULL];
        NSArray * arrayField67 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//Node/Field67" error:NULL];

        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF43 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF44 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF118 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF119 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF117 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * arrayFieldF67 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSString * Key1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString * Key2 = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString * OneTime = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString * DeviceID = [[NSString alloc]init];

        NSString *ResponseCode = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSString *ResponseDescription = [[NSString alloc]init];

        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField43 in arrayField43) {
            //Decrypt method
            NSString *tempKey1 = [eleField43 stringValue];

            NSData * data1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKey1];
            NSData * dataKey1 = [crypto decrypt:data1 key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKey1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKey1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            ResponseCode = resultKey1;
            [arrayFieldF43 addObject:ResponseCode];
        }

        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField44 in arrayField44) {
            //Decrypt method

            NSString *tempKey1 = [eleField44 stringValue];

            NSData * data1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKey1];
            NSData * dataKey1 = [crypto decrypt:data1 key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKey1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKey1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            ResponseDescription = resultKey1;
            [arrayFieldF44 addObject:ResponseDescription];
        }

        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField118 in arrayField118) {                         
            //Decrypt method

            NSString *tempKey1 = [eleField118 stringValue];

            NSData * data1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKey1];
            NSData * dataKey1 = [crypto decrypt:data1 key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKey1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKey1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            Key2 = resultKey1;
            [arrayFieldF118 addObject:Key2];

        }
        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField117 in arrayField117) {
            //Decrypt method

            NSString *tempKey3 = [eleField117 stringValue];

            NSData * data3 = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKey3];
            NSData * dataKey3= [crypto decrypt:data3 key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKey3= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKey3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            Key1 = resultKey3;
            [arrayFieldF117 addObject:Key1];
        }

        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField119 in arrayField119) {
            //Decrypt method

            NSString *tempKeyOneTime = [eleField119 stringValue];

            NSData * dataOneTime = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKeyOneTime];
            NSData * dataKeyOneTime= [crypto decrypt:dataOneTime key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKey2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKeyOneTime encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            OneTime = resultKey2;
            [arrayFieldF119 addObject:OneTime];

            // NSLog(@"One Time Password ::::::::: %@",OneTime);
        }

        for (GDataXMLElement *eleField67 in arrayField67) {
            //Decrypt method

            NSString *tempKeyDID = [eleField67 stringValue];

            NSData * dataDID = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:tempKeyDID];
            NSData * dataKeyDID= [crypto decrypt:dataDID key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];

            NSString * resultKeyDID = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataKeyDID encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            DeviceID = resultKeyDID;
            [arrayFieldF67 addObject:DeviceID];
        }

        ObjectDynamic * dynamic=[[ObjectDynamic alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"Responese Description in QRConfirm %@",ResponseDescription);

        [activityView stopAnimating];
        activityView.hidden = TRUE;
        imgVLoading.hidden = TRUE;

        if ([ResponseDescription isEqualToString:@"Success"])
        {
            AppDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

            dynamic.Key_1=Key1;
            dynamic.key_2=Key2;
            [delegate.db updatetKey:dynamic];

            [delegate showLoginByVID:QRRESULT];

        }
        else
        {
            //Do Something
        }

        [nodeContent release];

        [doc release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Point out QRConfirmViewController.m line 583.

Comment: Line -583 is only init : GDataXMLDocument * doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]init];

Comment: Which selector does not exist?  The exception printed as part of the crash log should tell you which.